# Issues involving Complex numbers and Integration when simplifying the question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

Yesterday while learning new integration techniques I stumbled upon the one where we can replace sinx as Img(e^1x) and tried using this for many types of questions. But somehow it didn't seem to work with questions with a log for example:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsqJB.jpg)
**I meant (pi^2)/8

So could you please correct me with the mistake being made here ?

Comment: Complex valued log behaves differently.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out !

Comment: You also "factored out" the Im[]? In general $f(Im(z))\neq Im(f(z))$. e.g.  $(Im[i])^2=(1)^2=1\neq 0=Im(i^2)$

Comment: Ohh yeah, got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $\sin x = \operatorname{Im} e^{ix} $ for real $x$.  But it is not true that $\ln(\sin x) = \operatorname{Im} \ln(e^{ix})$.

In fact:
$$
\ln(\sin x) = \ln(\operatorname{Im} e^{ix})
$$
but in general
$$
\ln(\operatorname{Im} e^{ix}) \ne 
\operatorname{Im} \ln(e^{ix})
$$

---

I wrote $\operatorname{Im} $ for "imaginary part".